# can swim without losing sight of land

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is from a children's book:

> Dazzling coral reefs are just a short distance offshore. Beginning snorkelers can swim without losing sight of land.

Does the second sentence mean:

a. Beginning snorkelers can swim here, as long as they don't swim too far away (not to lose sight of land), or

b. Even beginning snorkelers can swim to the coral reefs. Because it's a short distance they won't lose sight of land.

Comment: It means that there is an interesting underwater attraction so close to shore that a snorkeler is able to swim out to it and still be able to see the beach, which would give a novice snorkeler greater confidence. That is the implication, at any rate.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is B.

"can swim without losing sight of land" is a statement of safety and security. It doesn't tell the diver not to swim to far from the land but rather suggests that beginner divers will be safe if they stick to normal diving procedures because they will be able to see the land at all times.

Comment: I don't consider that an error in colloquial English, and I'm a native speaker.

Comment: You should add an explanation for the error you mention, rather than just say it is wrong.

Comment: Nonsense, @warhansen. There is no error. "Beginning snorkelers" is perfectly correct English. It isn't even idiomatic. "Beginner snorkelers" is also correct, but a native speaker would almost always use the first construction.

Comment: I apologise, I have removed the 2nd part of my answer. I still stick to the ACTUAL answer though.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.